# Como puedo obtener la activity actual de android?

Tags: java, android, activity

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas de apps android en eclipse, y tengo un método para dar clic la flecha de atrás al cual le paso una `Activity`:

```
public void flechaAtras(Activity activity) {
    Display mdisp = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point mdispSize = new Point();
    mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
    int maxX = mdispSize.x; 
    int maxY = mdispSize.y;

    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(getDriver());
    touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates (250, maxY - 80)).perform();
}
```

¿Como puedo obtener la activity que le envío?

Comment: Es importante definas en tu pregunta, desde donde la estas llamando.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente con un .this despues del nombre de tu clase puedes hacerlo

```
NombreDeTuActivity.this
```

Comment: Gracias, pero si no sé el nombre de activity. Esque estoy con pruebas de aplicaciones desde eclipse, no desde el Android Studio

Comment: No entiendo este comentario, ¿podrías definir que es activitysque?

Comment: Me equivoqué al escribir ya lo he corregido

Comment: Es el nombre de la clase con la que estés trabajando. Si estás trabajando con MainActivity.java -> MainActivity.this

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener las `Activity` actual la cual se enviaría al método  `flechaAtras(...)` puedes realizarlo de diferentes maneras:

Si te encuentras en una Activity, usa `this` :

```
flechaAtras(this);
```

Si te encuentras en una Activity, pero a su vez dentro de un listener, debes usar el nombre de la clase `MyActivity.this` :

```
flechaAtras(MyActivity.this);
```

Si te encuentras en un Fragment, usa `getActivity()` :

```
flechaAtras(getActivity());
```

Si te encuentras en una clase la cual no extiende de `Activity` o `Fragment`, es necesario enviar al constructor de esta clase el valor de `Actvity`:

```
flechaAtras(valorActivity);
```